# Yesterday Date Format as Short Date

Tags: apex

How do I show yesterday date as short date?

system.debug(Date.today().addDays(-1));

Thanks,

-Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:    `DateTime.now().addDays(-1).format('dd-MM-yyyy')`

Comment: sorry to trouble you again.  My custom field is a short date field (Closed_Date2__c).  How would I go about setting this field to yesteday date?        Closed_Date2__c = DateTime.now().addDays(-1).format('dd-MM-yyyy');

Comment: @user7123 I am not quite sure what do you mean? Is that a date field or a string field?

Comment: Closed_Date2__c is a Date Field.

Comment: I think I got it.  I just need to format all dates into a string and then do comparison between the dates.  Thank you much.